# Saving JTable as a textfile

Tags: java, swing, jtable, export

Im making a medical resource management system and i am using a text file to import the first set of Doctors. This is working fine and i have added the ability to remove a selected row, which is also working. However i want this change to become permanent and save on the text.

When i press my save button on the Java GUI i just clears the entire text file. I also have the ability the add separate doctors which is also working correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code for exporting the Jtable to the text file!

```
      private void jButtonSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEventevt) 
                 {                                            
             String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Stephen\\folder\\Programming 
               Assignment copy\\doctor.txt";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        for(int i = 0; i < jTableDoc.getRowCount(); i++){//rows
            for(int j = 0; j < jTableDoc.getColumnCount(); j++){//columns
                bw.write(jTableDoc.getValueAt(i, j).toString()+",");
            }
         bw.newLine();
        }

        bw.close();
        fw.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(doctorTable.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Comment: Assuming that there are no exceptions, make sure that there are rows and columns in the table

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).